# padding to main div push both main div and its child element to right

Tags: html, css, padding

I have main div and inner input element with 100% width. when i give padding:15px to main div, it pushes the both element  to right.

I make input element width  95% but still not working. Below is my code.

```css
header {
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #25b99a;
  float:left;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0; 
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.20);
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}

header input {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  float: left; 
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  -o-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text">
  <button></button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `box-sizing:border-box` : The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin.

**Fix it:**

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #25b99a;
  float:left;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0; 
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.20);
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}

header input{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  float: left;    
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  -o-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <input type="text">
  <button></button>
</header>
```